# Build only one executable for Kotlin/Native project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

Kotlin/Native [allows to produce multiple binaries](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2505).

```
kotlin {
    binaries {
        executable()                       // Executable with default name.
        executable("foo")                  // Custom binary name.
        executable("bar", listOf(RELEASE)) // Custom build types.
        ...
    }
}
```

`gradle build` will trigger build for each executable. At some point it's starting to take a long time to make all the executable binaries. Is it possible to build only one executable? Something like `gradle buildFoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tasks with names constructed as `run(execName)(buildtype)Executable(OS)` that the Gradle plugin generates by himself. Also, you can use a task `link(execName)(buildtype)Executable(OS)` to produce a binary file.